# Can NetBeans 8.0 with Scala and sbt plugins installed create sbt project?

Tags: scala, netbeans, sbt

I had previously used [Scala-IDE](http://scala-ide.org/), and I thought I'd give [NetBeans IDE 8.0](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/) a try.

I created Java/Maven projects successfully, but I don't seem to be able to create an sbt project.  I have all the Scala plugins loaded as far as I can see, including the sbt plugin.  Platform is Win 8.1 and Java 8.

Creating an NetBeans native project for Scala works, but there seems to be no option to create an sbt project. Is that expected?

Comment: I've never worked with NB and Scala/sbt, and searching for "netbeans sbt plugin" yields at least three different sbt plugins for NB. What plugin do you use? Can you attach a screenshot of the plugin installed in the plugin manager to the question?

Answer (score 4):

*Iff* the plugin you use is [nbscala-1.6.3.1](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/54162/nbscala-1-6-3-1) it appears from [the documentation](https://github.com/dcaoyuan/nbscala#supported-features) that the supported features are:

> - Recognize sbt project and open in NetBeans
> - Open sbt console in NetBeans (Right click on sbt project, choose "Open Sbt")
> - Jump to/Open compile error lines

I conclude that there's **no support for creating a new sbt project** using the plugin.

You'd have to create a sbt project using [Typesafe Activator](http://typesafe.com/activator) and only then use NetBeans with the plugin to open it and start hacking right in the environment.

Comment: It is 1.6.3.1.  So I guess that's the case.  I'd read that but twigged that it might imply that you can't start such a project.  Thanks.